# Make a bootable USB from an ISO

Tags: linux, usb-drive, iso, bootable

I'm trying to copy entire iso including mbr into a usb device, the iso is an output of kernel compilation with `make isoimage`, the problem is it won't boot from the usb.

Thanks.

**fdisk on the USB device**

```
$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdc

Disk /dev/sdc: 15.4 GB, 15376000000 bytes, 30031250 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

**linux.iso file**

```
$ file -s linux.iso 
linux.iso: # ISO 9660 CD-ROM filesystem data 'CDROM' (bootable)
```

**dd command i used in order to copy the ISO contents into the USB**

```
$ dd if=linux.iso of=/dev/sdc bs=1MB
```

Comment: Unless your `iso` was a `Hybrid iso`, you will need to make the `USB` bootable yourself. Check out this link: http://www.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php?title=Isohybrid

Answer (score 1):

Like Peschke said, you need to make it bootable. If you have access to a GUI, try Gnome Disks. Fire it up, click on your USB Flash Drive on the left panel, and in the right panel, underneath the partition map, click the small gears icon. Click "Edit Partition", and check the checkmark next to the word "Bootable". It will probably ask you for your password, type it in, and press enter. Remember, not all computers/BIOS's support booting from USB, so don't give your hopes up.

Comment: `make isoimage` creates hybrid iso `genisoimage -J -r -o $(obj)/image.iso -b isolinux.bin -c boot.cat \
                -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table \
                $(obj)/isoimage`
        `isohybrid $(obj)/image.iso 2>/dev/null || true`